# Postgres imported tables are not shown and "already exists" error occur when create manually

Tags: postgresql

I ran command import tables from "xxx.sql" into Postgres database `test`, it shows all tables are created but when I run `\dt` in database `test`, it shows "Didn't find any relations" but when I try to create table manually, it shows "relation xxx already exists"

```
test=# create table test.order_product
(
    id                serial primary key,
    quantity          integer,
    order_id          integer references test.order (id),
);
ERROR:  relation "order_product" already exists
test=# select * from order_product;
ERROR:  relation "order_product" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from order_product;
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Below is the version information:

```
 PostgreSQL 12.4 (Debian 12.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

Comment: The table is exists in the schema `test` and you are trying to get it from `public` schema. When you do `select * from order_product;` it will goes to public schema to get the result. To get it from test schema you need `select * from test.order_product;`.

Comment: @MAK I tried it, still not work.

Comment: When you do `\dt` it will show the schema name with table details, just check the schema the table belongs to.

Comment: @MAK thanks, now I get it. I have created database 'test' and the schema name is "test" as well. I am new to postgres and just found the difference between database and schema, THANKS again!